# Loading HTML5/js into WebView fails on Nexus7 running KitKat, but ok on phone running Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to load an HTML5 / Javascript game into a WebView.

Since this works on an old phone running Gingerbread but fails on a Nexus7 running KitKat, I'm guessing maybe it's something to do with the new Chromium based WebView in Android 4.4?
The game works fine in the Chrome Browser on the Nexus7, but not in the WebView in my app.

Any advice where I should be looking to track down the source of this problem would be greatly appreciated.

The LogCat when I run on the Nexus7 is:

```
05-29 13:49:46.421    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GameActivity﹕ Logged into Facebook
05-29 13:49:46.421    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GameActivity﹕ mNewCheckin = false
05-29 13:49:47.371    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GameActivity﹕ checkInToPlay()
05-29 13:49:47.371    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GameActivity﹕ Showing Game
05-29 13:49:47.371    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx V/WebViewChromium﹕ Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {4204a888}
05-29 13:49:47.371    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
05-29 13:49:47.381    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/BrowserProcessMain﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
05-29 13:49:47.381    2526-2563/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
05-29 13:49:47.421    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ Loading URL into WebView
05-29 13:49:47.491    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
05-29 13:49:47.501    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ Page Started Loading...
05-29 13:49:47.501    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageStarted:WebView ID: 2131296360
05-29 13:49:47.501    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageStarted:URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html
05-29 13:49:47.621    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "Viewport argument key "minimal-ui" not recognized and ignored.", source: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html (9)
05-29 13:49:48.951    2526-2540/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx W/ContextImpl﹕ Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.connect:82 com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService:330
05-29 13:49:48.951    2526-2540/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx W/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
05-29 13:49:48.961    2526-2540/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
05-29 13:49:49.381    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ ...Page Finished Loading
05-29 13:49:49.381    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:WebView ID: 2131296360
05-29 13:49:49.381    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html
05-29 13:49:49.411    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
05-29 13:49:49.431    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
05-29 13:49:49.681    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(153)] "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.", source: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/c2runtime.js (153)
05-29 13:49:49.781    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ ...Page Finished Loading
05-29 13:49:49.781    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:WebView ID: 2131296360
05-29 13:49:49.781    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html
05-29 13:49:49.931    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ ...Page Finished Loading
05-29 13:49:49.931    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:WebView ID: 2131296360
05-29 13:49:49.931    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html
05-29 13:49:49.971    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ ...Page Finished Loading
05-29 13:49:49.971    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:WebView ID: 2131296360
05-29 13:49:49.971    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html
05-29 13:49:49.991    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
05-29 13:49:50.081    2526-2601/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
05-29 13:49:50.081    2526-2564/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
05-29 13:49:50.081    2526-2600/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
05-29 13:49:50.131    2526-2564/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
05-29 13:49:50.151    2526-2601/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
05-29 13:49:50.231    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ ...Page Finished Loading
05-29 13:49:50.231    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:WebView ID: 2131296360
05-29 13:49:50.231    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/GamePlayFragment﹕ onPageFinished:URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html
05-29 13:49:51.011    2526-2526/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.", source: https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=.........
05-29 13:49:53.961    2526-2592/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx W/ContextImpl﹕ Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsGmsCoreClient.connect:82 com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService:330
05-29 13:49:53.971    2526-2592/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx W/GAV3﹕ Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
05-29 13:49:54.001    2526-2592/au.com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1133K, 11% free 10204K/11372K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
```

Here's how I'm currently implementing the WebView.

```
    // webview
    final WebView webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.game_webview);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.xxxxxxx.xxx.xx/xxxxx/xxx/index.html");
```

Comment: "After a lot of googling it seems this could be caused by the use of relative references in the html" -- relative references are never a problem with `loadUrl()`, to the best of my knowledge. Relative references can be a problem with `loadData()`, but not `loadUrl()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Thanks. I guess I missunderstood and have been looking down the wrong track. Any suggestions what may be more likely to be causing these errors on a Nexus7 running KitKat, but not on an old phone running Gingerbread?

Comment: Off the cuff, I haven't a clue. I would check your LogCat for lines immediately around the "MediaResourceGetter﹕ Invalid url" line to see if you can determine what URL it is complaining about, as that might help narrow things down a bit. Similarly, if that error line is part of a larger stack trace, you might consider editing your question and providing the full stack trace, as that might give us more clues.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Have revised the question as suggested.

Comment: I would research some of those `chromium` messages, such as `Async pixel transfers not supported` and `Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.", source: http://www.xxxxxxx.com.au/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx/c2runtime.js`

Comment: @SoundConception have you found the solution, facing same issue on Kitkat(HTC) but works well on Lollipop!